# How to plot geoTiff file with shape file and lat long gridlines using python?

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff

I am trying to plot a GeoTiff file using python as given in the example (https://www.neonscience.org/plot-neon-rgb-py#comment-668). This script convert GeoTIFF file into the true-color image which likes how human eyes would see. I could plot the GeoTIFF but I want to overlay a shapefile and lat and long grid lines.

```
import gdal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


def RGBraster2array(RGB_geotif):
    """RGBraster2array reads in a NEON AOP geotif file and returns 
    a numpy array, and header containing associated metadata with spatial information.
    --------
    Parameters
        RGB_geotif -- full or relative path and name of reflectance hdf5 file
    --------
    Returns 
    --------
    array:
        numpy array of geotif values
    metadata:
        dictionary containing the following metadata (all strings):
            array_rows
            array_cols
            bands
            driver
            projection
            geotransform 
            pixelWidth 
            pixelHeight 
            extent
            noDataValue  
            scaleFactor 
    --------
    Example Execution:
    --------
    RGB_geotif = '2017_SERC_2_368000_4306000_image.tif'
    RGBcam_array, RGBcam_metadata = RGBraster2array(RGB_geotif) """

    metadata = {}
    dataset = gdal.Open(RGB_geotif)
    metadata['array_rows'] = dataset.RasterYSize
    metadata['array_cols'] = dataset.RasterXSize
    metadata['bands'] = dataset.RasterCount
    metadata['driver'] = dataset.GetDriver().LongName
    metadata['projection'] = dataset.GetProjection()
    metadata['geotransform'] = dataset.GetGeoTransform()

    mapinfo = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
    metadata['pixelWidth'] = mapinfo[1]
    metadata['pixelHeight'] = mapinfo[5]

    metadata['ext_dict'] = {}
    metadata['ext_dict']['xMin'] = mapinfo[0]
    metadata['ext_dict']['xMax'] = mapinfo[0] + dataset.RasterXSize/mapinfo[1]
    metadata['ext_dict']['yMin'] = mapinfo[3] + dataset.RasterYSize/mapinfo[5]
    metadata['ext_dict']['yMax'] = mapinfo[3]

    metadata['extent'] = (metadata['ext_dict']['xMin'],metadata['ext_dict']['xMax'],
                          metadata['ext_dict']['yMin'],metadata['ext_dict']['yMax'])

    raster = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
    array_shape = raster.ReadAsArray(0,0,metadata['array_cols'],metadata['array_rows']).astype(np.float).shape
    metadata['noDataValue'] = raster.GetNoDataValue()
    metadata['scaleFactor'] = raster.GetScale()

    array = np.zeros((array_shape[0],array_shape[1],dataset.RasterCount),'uint8') #pre-allocate stackedArray matrix
    for i in range(1, dataset.RasterCount+1):
        band = dataset.GetRasterBand(i).ReadAsArray(0,0,metadata['array_cols'],metadata['array_rows']).astype(np.float)
        band[band==metadata['noDataValue']]=np.nan
        band = band/metadata['scaleFactor']
        array[...,i-1] = band

    return array, metadata

RGB_geotif = '/home/krishna/Desktop/Py_works/geo/True_color.tiff'
SERC_RGBcam_array, SERC_RGBcam_metadata = RGBraster2array(RGB_geotif)

SERC_RGBcam_array.shape

#Display information stored in header
for key in sorted(SERC_RGBcam_metadata.keys()):
  print(key)

def plot_band_array(band_array,
                    refl_extent,
                    colorlimit,
                    ax=plt.gca(),
                    title='',
                    cbar ='on',
                    cmap_title='',
                    colormap='spectral'):

    '''plot_band_array reads in and plots a single band or an rgb band combination of a reflectance array
    --------
    Parameters
    --------
        band_array: flightline array of reflectance values, created from h5refl2array function
        refl_extent: extent of reflectance data to be plotted (xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax) - use metadata['extent'] from h5refl2array function
        colorlimit: range of values to plot (min,max). Best to look at the histogram of reflectance values before plotting to determine colorlimit.
        ax: optional, default = current axis
        title: string, optional; plot title
        cmap_title: string, optional; colorbar title
        colormap: string, optional; see https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html for list of colormaps
    --------
    Returns 
        plots array of single band or RGB if given a 3-band 
    --------
    Example:
    --------
    plot_band_array(SERC_RGBcam_array, 
                    SERC_RGBcam_metadata['extent'],
                    (1,255),
                    title='SERC RGB Camera Tile',
                    cbar='off')'''

    plot = plt.imshow(band_array,extent=refl_extent,clim=colorlimit); 
    if cbar == 'on':
        cbar = plt.colorbar(plot,aspect=40); plt.set_cmap(colormap); 
        cbar.set_label(cmap_title,rotation=90,labelpad=20)



  plot_band_array(SERC_RGBcam_array,
                SERC_RGBcam_metadata['extent'],
                (1,255),
                title='SERC RGB Camera Tile',
                cbar='off') 
    plt.savefig('/home/krishna/Desktop/Py_works/geo/PCorrected_reflectance', dpi=100)

    plt.show()
```

How to do that? I tried with cartopy to overlay the grid lines with ax, but that doesn't plotted the GeoTIFF file well. Someone could help me on this?

Comment: Or is there any better way to plot geotiff file into true color image with lats and lons without using this functions?